# What size-reduction to expect on average when gzipping MBtiles?

Tags: gzip, mapbox

As part of checking some prereqs for an idea (IOS app with [MBtiles](http://mapbox.com/developers/mbtiles/) on local storage enabeling offline maps) I'd like to know if it's useful to gzip MBtiles when transporting them to an IOS device.

In other words, is there a useful reduction in size when gzipping MBtiles? (or is the MBtile-format, already packed in some way, thus limiting the use of gzip or other packers).

If so, how much size reduction can I expect?  (percentage ballpark)

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43916/what-size-reduction-can-i-expect-on-average-when-gzipping-mbtiles

Answer (score 0):

-rw-r--r--  1 randycarver  wheel  105484288 Apr  9 11:05 gc_40_16.mbtiles
-rw-r--r--  1 randycarver  wheel  101777468 Apr 21 06:03 gc_40_16.mbtiles.gz

I'm seeing around 4% size reduction.

Comment: How are you doing the conversion from mbtiles to mbtiles.gz? Could you help me with that please?

Comment: this was simply a test at gzipping the entire mbtiles file to see if the reduction would help when transporting the file to the device.